# My HP PAVILLON stop working suddenly from time to time

Tags: linux

I got a new HP Pavillon laptop.

PU: Quad Core AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 1371/1600/2000 MHz Kernel: 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64 Up: 2m 
Mem: 703.6/11727.0 MiB (6.0%) Storage: 1.60 TiB (43.6% used) Procs: 257 
Shell: bash 4.4.19 inxi: 3.0.27

uname -a
Linux xxx-HP 4.15.0-52-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 22:49:08 
ULinux xxx-HP 4.15.0-52-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 22:49:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
TC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

It turns out that the keyboard and the mouse stop working suddenly and the external hard disk light is on.

Any idea about the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bad hard drive blocking IO. What are the S.M.A.R.T results?

Comment: Thansk. Well, SMART results are:

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

Comment: Anyway I've been googling and I've found this page  where you can read a solution. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Keyboard-stops-working/m-p/6279906#M471971

Someone says:

Comment: The solution hasn't worker. After several days the problem is here. Again.